# Json getting error 400

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to get the json from a link page.

The links works perfect when I open into the browser

here is the code I get an error 400 in the console. However, If I paste this url in my browser I get the page, any ideas what can be? and how to fix?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#get-data').click(function () {
    var showData = $('#show-data');

    $.getJSON('http://example.com', function (data) {
      console.log(data);

     showData.html(JSON.stringify(data))

    });

    showData.text('Loading the JSON file.');
  });
});
```

**json in the url:**

```
{
    "day": 0,
    "people": 0,
    "total": 22,
    "tests": []
}
```

**Status Code:400 Bad Request**

Comment: We can't tell why the server side code for a secret URL is returning a 400 error for a request without seeing the code for it

Comment: What's the 400 error message? "Not allowed"?

Comment: Status Code:400 Bad Request

Comment: Can you show us the url?

Comment: Are you getting your JSON from the same domain from your code ?

Comment: I am getting from local machine to a https unfortunately I can share the url :(

Comment: @Raduken try with `jsonp`

Comment: thanks @7urkm3n can you show me how? i have no much experience with that, thank you

Comment: @Raduken `$.get(url, function(data){console.log(data); }, 'jsonp');`

Comment: @Raduken so any news, did it work ?

Comment: I could not do, I am not so good with jquery  sorry.

Comment: @Raduken can u snap yr json data and share the link im not use its json, otherwise it should work

Answer (score 1):

Using `$.getJSON` sends to the server that the client accepts `application/json`. It could be that the webserver is checking for the accepted type, and since it can't serve JSON on the requested endpoint, it'll give back a 400 error. (which is an error made on the client side)

We however can't say if this is the case for sure, since you didn't say which URL you're trying this on and what the URL is configured to send back on that endpoint.